# fix body when bootstrap navbar collapse

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#about">                  
                About
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">                  
                Contact
            </a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

The above is the code of bootstrap navbar header which collapses when screen size decreases. Could anyone help me to make the body position fixed only when the navbar header dropdown is open.

Thanks.

Comment: Which collapses? Can you make a demo of your full code in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) is what you need.

```
if (!$("relevant-div").hasClass("open-class")){ // or collapse class
   $("body").toggleClass("body-fixed");
}
```

---

```
.body-fixed { // sample
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct and this code is working fine to make the body position fixed but it should remove the body-fixed class when the menu is closed. It is not removing the class from body even though I wrote removeClass condition in else.

Comment: You need .toggleClass() for that;  I updated my answer. Enjoy

Comment: @Avni I know :) I've had to do this one a few times

Comment: How is this done on Bootstrap 3? I tried this with "open" and "in" instead of open-class but it kept applying the "body-fixed" class to the page immediately on load even though the navbar was not yet opened.